# Blogger: problem with blogger sitemap "couldn't fetch"

Tags: html

My blogger sitemap shows "couldn't fetch" but my domain name is [techbeast.cc](https://www.techbeast.cc/), is there a problem with my domain?

I have tried lots of things like

- atom.xml
- sitemap.xml
- rss.xml

but all are the same problem. but my robots.txt file has no issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.